# .notify() isn't notifying .wait() for a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been having trouble trying to get a waited thread to by notified.

Here is the code for where the `notify()` is called:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int endUsers = 0;
        Terminal terminal = new Terminal("Master");
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        threads.add(new Thread(
                new EndUser("EndUser 1", DEFAULT_DST_NODE, 50000, 50001),
                "EndUser 1"));
        endUsers++;
        threads.add(new Thread(
                new EndUser("EndUser 2", DEFAULT_DST_NODE, 50001, 50000),
                "EndUser 2"));
        endUsers++;

        for (Thread t : threads)
        {
            t.start();
        }

        while (true)
        {
            int user = terminal.readInt("Which user is sending data?  ");
            if (user <= endUsers && user > 0)
            {
                synchronized (threads.get(user - 1))
                {
                    threads.get(user - 1).notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code where `wait()` is called:

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                this.wait();
            }
            this.send();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Where is `run()` defined? Are you sure `this` is a `Thread`? Btw, you should never wait on threads.

Comment: It's in a class that implements Runnable

Comment: That much is fairly obvious.

Comment: Have you tried creating an Object reference (Object o = new Object()), and using that (o.wait() o.notify()) instead? To my knowledge, that generally works.

Comment: Also want to point out that the waiting object is waiting on the runnable, not the thread. Thread.getCurrentThread().wait() would be appropriate, given the notify context.

Comment: You should not use wait/notify on Thread objects. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
threads.get(user - 1).notify();
```

is invoking notify on the Thread object, where

```
this.wait();
```

is waiting on your runnable, or the class in which the call is housed.
Using

```
Thread.currentThread().wait();
```

should fix your issue.

In addition, I would like to mention that creating an Object reference, then waiting on and notifying that would be a fully functional method to obtain what you want as well

You would create the Object as a(n) (optionally static) reference in your thread class

```
public final (static) Object waitObject = new Object();
```

> Edit: ^ Making this final prevents other (likely malicious) code parts
>   from reassigning the value, which would make it so that the waitObject.notify()
>   method is never actually able to be reached.

Then use

```
waitObject.wait();  //or
waitObject.wait(time);
```

And

```
waitObject.notify();  //or
waitObject.notifyAll();
```

Edit:
As was pointed out by @shmosel, it is inherently unsafe to use "wait", "sleep", or "notify" from within a thread, as outlined within the Java Documentation. However, despite this, the functionality is still available for use, though discouraged.

For additional Java references you have multiple resources available to you; such as.:
[Java API Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), [Java Thread API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), [This Google Search - Safe Java Practices](https://www.google.ca/search?q=safe%20java%20practices) (to which you can append what you are looking into, such as "Threading, Wait" for a search query of "Safe Java Practices Threading, Wait"), and many more.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad that I could help. Don't forget to accept the provided answer, please. And an upvote would always be appreciated, as well. :)

Comment: [*It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-)

Comment: I don't argue that statement, nor am i encouraging that the OP do so. However, that statement does not answer the question that the OP asked and is, therefore, irrelevant.

Comment: @shmosel, I included some links and a statement that the attempted activities are unsafe practices. Hopefully that's good enough for you (not to be rude)

Comment: Every statement that doesn't answer OP's question is irrelevant? What are comments for then?